# ¿Refactorización para métodos de una sola llamada o agrupar métodos?

Tags: c#, algoritmos

Saludos! ¿Que es recomendado para las buena practicas? ¿Aplicar “Inline Method - Refactoring” para métodos que solo se llaman una sola vez? o ¿permitir que el método se mantenga en una clase que tiene la intención de clasificar ciertos comportamientos?

Ejemplo:

El módulo Cotizaciones tiene un conjunto de contactos para enviar Emails, se obtienen con los siguientes métodos.

```
Collection<MCotizacionContacto> GetContactos(E2ContactosTipos enm_ContactoTipo);
Collection<MCotizacionContacto> GetContactos(E2ContactosTipos enm_ContactoTipo, int int_ContactoId,
```

Cada método llama respectivamente a los métodos:

```
void SetCotizacionContactosEnvioAll(Collection<MCotizacionContacto> collectionCotizacionContactoM);
void SetCotizacionContactosEnvioOne(Collection<MCotizacionContacto> collectionCotizacionContactoM, int int_ContactoIdReenvio);
```

Estos dos últimos métodos son factible de aplicar la Refactorización “Inline method” porque solo se llaman una sola vez; pero a su vez, se cree que sus nombres están bien clasificados dentro de la clase que los contiene. Además es factible aplicarlo en el posible módulo futuro Pedidos.

¿Está relacionado con algún “Patrón de Diseño” en particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal es que un clase sea responsable de una sola tarea, asi es mas facil de entender para otro desarrollador que vea el código, y es mas fácil de mantener.

si quieres saber mas aacerca de buenas practicas en C# leete este libro, es muy bueno (esta en ingles) [Object Oriented Programming in C# Succinctly](https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebookconfirm/oop-csharp/sitevisitors)

Suerte!

Comment: gracias por la luz y el recurso. Entiendo que “la mejor solución es la que sea más fácil de entender en el futuro”. Justo ahí estoy estancado, la cuestión es decidir que es mejor ¿Poner todo “Inline” para evitar la revisión de otros métodos? O ¿Agrupar métodos comunes, por decirlo de alguna manera, para intentar dar más claridad a la estructura? Algo así como decidir entre “Principio de responsabilidad única” o “Divide y vencerás”.

Comment: en mi opinión, deberías mantener el principio de única responsabilidad, dado que al momento de hacer un cambio a esa responsabilidad, solo
 deberás buscar en un lugar o archivo. yo refactorizaría para dejar el método con un nombre y distinguirlo solo por la firma (así como MsgBox que utiliza un método u otro dependiendo de los parámetros).

Comment: Gracias! Tu opinión me ayudo con la solución final. Todo el código debe mantener en la misma Clase si aplica el Principio de Responsabilidad Única. Sin embargo, he concluido que el punto clave está en la abstracción del problema. Lo que debo definir claramente es si la Clase compartirá en el futuro algún en común con otra. En mi ejemplo, si solo se creará el módulo de Cotizaciones entonces debe realizarse la refactorización “Inline”. Debemos estar seguros de la abstracción, si referenciamos la “Paradoja de Schrödinger” no podemos asumir que el gato este vivo y muerto al mismo tiempo.